# Python multiple processes do not loop on for

Tags: python, optimization, graph, multiprocessing

I'm working on the implementation of several algorithms to compute shortest paths on graphs.

I have managed to implement Dijkstra's algorithm sequentially and I'm now trying to optimize my algorithm through the multiprocessing module of Python.

As a whole the code works. What I am trying to do here is :

- First to check how many cpus I can work on with `nb_cpu = mp.cpu_count()`
- Then dividing all the nodes I have in my graph accordingly
- Finally calling the method `subprocess_dijkstra` that should compute the dijkstra algorithm for each of the nodes it is given as an argument (the idea being that each process only has to compute the algorithm for a smaller part of the graph).

When I run my script (called from a main.py file where I just format the data to suit my needs), I have 4 processes launched as I should.

However, they do not seem to execute the `for node in nodes` loop defined in `subprocess_dijkstra`.

Each process only computes the code once and then they go on hold indefinitely...

It is my first attempt at multiprocessing under Python so I may have missed a detail. Does anybody have an idea ?

When I interrupt the script, python tells me that the interruption takes place on the `p.join()` line.

Thanks to anyone helping me :)

Here is my code :

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def subprocess_dijkstra(do_print, nodes, tab_contenu, tab_distances):
    tab_dist_initial = dict(tab_distances)
    tab_dist = dict()
    for node in nodes:
        visited_nodes = list()
        tab_dist = dict(tab_dist_initial)
        dmin = -1
        resultat = ""
        filename = "dijkstra"+str(node)+".txt"

        if do_print:
            dt = open(filename, 'w')
            tab_dist[node] = 0

            """Ligne de résultat initiale"""
            for valeur in tab_dist.values():
                resultat += str(valeur)
                resultat += " "
            resultat += "\n"

            dt.write(resultat)

        while len(visited_nodes) != len(tab_contenu):
            """ On se place sur le noeud non visité qui a la distance minimale de notre départ """
            for cle, valeur in tab_dist.items():
                if cle not in visited_nodes:
                    if dmin ==-1 or valeur<dmin:
                        dmin = valeur
                        node = cle


            """ On vérifie que le noeud n'a pas déjà été visité """
            if (node not in visited_nodes):
                """ On regarde les fils de ce noeud et la longueur des arcs"""
                for cle,valeur in tab_contenu[node].items():
                    tab_dist[cle] = min(tab_dist[cle], tab_dist[node]+valeur)

                visited_nodes.append(node)

                if do_print:
                    resultat = ""
                    """ Ligne de résultat """
                    for valeur in tab_dist.values():
                        resultat += str(valeur)
                        resultat += " "
                    resultat += "\n"

                    dt.write(resultat)

        if do_print:
            dt.close()


def main(do_print,donnees):

    tab_contenu = donnees[1]
    nb_nodes = int(donnees[0])
    tab_distances = {x: float('inf') for x in range(nb_nodes)}
    args=[(do_print, x, tab_contenu, tab_distances) for x in range(nb_nodes)]
    nb_cpu = mp.cpu_count()


    pool = mp.Pool(processes = nb_cpu)
    pool.starmap(subprocess_dijkstra, args)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the source of my problems.

The `tab_dist[node] = 0` was misplaced and should have been put before the `if do_print:` statement.

All is now working.